# extend, stringify, and isPlainObject

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find out how this code works:

```
  <script>
  var object1 = {
      apple: 0,
      banana: {weight: 52, price: 100},
      cherry: 97
  };
  var object2 = {
     banana: {price: 200},
     durian: 100
  };

  /* merge object2 into object1 */
  $.extend(object1, object2);

  var printObj = typeof JSON != "undefined" 
       ? JSON.stringify : function(obj) {
    var arr = [];
  $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
      var next = key + ": ";
      next += $.isPlainObject(val) ? printObj(val) : val;
      arr.push( next );
  });
  return "{ " +  arr.join(", ") + " }";
  };

  $("#log").append( printObj(object1) );
  </script>
```

I understand what `stringify()` and `isPlainObject()` are doing, I have been testing the code, and I realize that `function(obj)` is not used? This is really confusing. I dont get it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: nice reference! thanks soo much

Comment: to explain directly, function(obj) is providing a *fallback* for browsers which don't have the JSON built-in object.

Comment: if test it in IE 8, it will be used

Comment: coool!!! that is excelent these comments help me to underestand finally this code... TX!!!